# External C# libraries on mobile

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, encog

Is it possible to use an external C# library in a unity project to be compiled for iOS and Android?

In my case I need to use the [encog](http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog) library in my game, will I encounter issues from the translation for native iOS/Android code?

Comment: the library in question needs to support the target platforms. If it doesn't say so assume it's windows-only or run a quick test.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the problem is that unity uses a version of .Net that is older than what Encog supports. More info on this question:

[Encog dll in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865859/encog-dll-in-unity)